# Not able to add reference to my project in the test project in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm writing my first C# program in Visual Studio for mac, and now I want to do unit testing for the code.

I can't add a reference to my original project. When I open the references dialog box it's empty and I'm not able to browse. The test file is in it's own project, therefore not the same namespace.

I followed these steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/walkthrough-creating-and-running-unit-tests-for-managed-code?view=vs-2022

The guide is not for mac but seems to work similar.

Comment: Are both projects in the same solution?

Comment: According to the documentation, there should not be a problem that the original project is not displayed. It is not in the same namespace as you described. If you try it, the reference will also be displayed.   Did you make sure that the test project and the original project are in the same solution and you can describe more specific to help you solve.